Which DSE version is compatible to import Cassandra 4.x SSTables?
Is there any DSE 6.x version supporting C* 4.x sstable format (-nb-)? I want to load data from apache C* 4.x using sstableloader into DSE 6.x. What would be the best recommended upgrade path (compatible) to import C* 4.x sstables into DSE 6.x?

DSE 6.x - protocol DSE_V2 - (sstable format -bb-)
C* 4.x - protocol v5 - (sstable format -nb-)

Using Apache Cassandra 4.x sstableloader -> The client is unable to negotiate a protocol even after adding application.conf (v4) in EXTRA_CLASSPATH as per doc. Error remains same irrespective of any provided compatible driver:
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnsupportedProtocolVersionException: \
  [/10.x.x.x:9042] Host does not support protocol version V6 but V5. 

Using DSE 6.8.x sstableloader -> Import of -nb- sstables from 4.x complete without errors but there are no files in /data path of DSE cluster and SELECT * from TABLE returns 0 rows. Using nodetool refresh and nodetool import doesn't seem to help.
There is no clear information of C* 4.x compatibility with DSE on Datastax documentation. Any links or information around this would be helpful. Thanks!

The storage engine in DataStax Enterprise (DSE) 6.8/6.9 is based on:

Apache Cassandra 3.11
PLUS enhancements which have been ported to newer C* versions

So even though DSE has advanced features that are only available in newer versions of Apache Cassandra, DSE is only supported to work with C* 3.x m* SSTable formats as documented in the DataStax Product Compatibility matrix, not the newer n* formats in C* 4.x.
The C* 3.x m* SSTable formats which are supported to work with DSE 6 are:

ma from 3.0.0
mb from 3.0.7, 3.7
mc from 3.0.8, 3.9
md from 3.0.18, 3.11.4
me from C* 3.0.25, 3.11.11

These C* SSTable formats are newer than the underlying C* version in DSE 6 so are not supported:

na from 4.0-rc1
nb from 4.0.0
oa from 5.0.0

If you attempt to load SSTables whose formats are not supported, the storage engine in DSE won't recognise those formats so will ignore them.
As a side note, DataStax Hyper-Converged Database (HCD) is a cloud-native distribution of Cassandra (meaning it is Kubernetes-ready) that is based on Apache Cassandra 4.x but has vector search capabilities for Gen AI apps and Data API included that provides developers API access to perform CRUD operations. HCD might be an option for you if you really need to work with C* 4.x SSTables but note that HCD is a completely different product to DSE.
For full disclosure since I've mentioned the company a number of times, I am an Apache Cassandra committer and I work at DataStax. Cheers!
